# openSUSE doesn't show some unicode characters

Tags: linux, fonts, kde, opensuse, unicode

I installed openSUSE 12.1 yesterday and it doesn't show some unicode characters, like Kannada characters.

I'm using KDE.

What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install package [`indic-fonts`](http://software.opensuse.org/package/indic-fonts).

Teaching you how to fish:

[Font Support for Unicode Block *Kannada*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/kannada/fontsupport.htm) lists fonts that have decent coverage. *GNU Unifont* is packaged as [`gnu-unifont`](http://software.opensuse.org/package/gnu-unifont). *Last Resort* and *Unicode BMP Fallback SIL* are [bogus](http://enwp.org/Fallback_font).

The other two mentioned there are available as downloads from the Web and require manual installation. Unpack the font files from the archive, if any. In a file manager, bring up the context menu for a font file and select `Actions` → `Install…`. The files should now show up under the `fonts:/` URI in Konqueror and a copy in the file system under the hidden directory `~/.fonts/`.

Restart any application in which you intend to intend to use a new font.